# Local js function to other site that will write a cookie

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

im the owner of domain `A.com` and `B.com`

in `B.com` i have handler (ashx) which writes a cookie.

now , im on A.com.

i want to call this handler from site  `A.com` via  `Js`(/jquery) that will activate the `B.com's` handler - and will write the cookie of B.com in My browser.

does jsonP will help me here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your own question, you can use jsonp for this. Some more info : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for something like [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/)

Comment: i know the workarounds like iframe and window.open but i want to understand why in jsonp i can access other site's url , and here i cant get his cookie

Comment: Code in the browser will be executed in the sandbox. If your code is downloaded from a.com it can never access the cookies of b.com domain even you get url using jsonp

Comment: i dont want to access the cookies of B ! i want to call the handler which on B and his job is already to write cookie.... what am i missing ?